# Access splitted table cell in Word with C#

Tags: c#, ms-word, interop

I'm splitting a cell into two columns:

```
table.Cell(1,1).Split(1,2);
```

How can I access the two new cells?

Comment: It would help a lot if more code were provided so that we could copy/paste as a starting point for testing. Then we'd also know how `table` is derived, for instance. In other words, a [mcve] - it would save those who take time out of their working day time and effort, not needing to guess and recreate from scratch...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with many things in Word, the trick to getting "pointers" to objects is to work with `Ranges`.

In this case, if a `Range` to the original cell is instantiated it's possible to refer back to it. After the split it will be in the first cell. From it, it's possible to get both the first and second cells (and, indeed, anything else in the table).

For example

```
Word.Table tbl = document.Tables[1];
Word.Cell cel = tbl.Cell(1, 1);
Word.Range rng = cel.Range;
cel.Split(1, 2);
//At this point, rng is at the start of the first (left-most) cell of the two
//using new objects for the split cells
Word.Cell newCel1 = rng.Cells[1];
Word.Cell newCel2 = rng.Next(wdCell, 1).Cells[1];
newCel1.Range.Text = "1";
newCel2.Range.Text = "2";
//Alternative: using the original cell, plus a new object for the split cell
//Word.Cell newCel2 = rng.Next(Word.WdUnits.wdCell, 1).Cells[1];
//cel.Range.Text = "1";
//newCel2.Range.Text = "2";
```